# How to call/run web page from powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm writing a powershell which needs to call one aspx page which internally applies some flags and transfers data etc.

I'm using the script below, the problem is it shows the HTML contents on powershell:

```
$w = Get-Url "http://www.w3.org"

$w = (new-object net.webclient).DownloadString("http://www.w3.org")
```

Is there any way or other functions where I can call the web page which doesn't get displayed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $w      = 'http://www.w3.org'
 $w_data = Invoke-WebRequest $w

#  e.g.
foreach ($weblink in $w_data.links)
{  #do something with the links }
```

Answer (score 0):

explorer file:///C:/Users/user/Hithere.html